# get photos array from google places api using nearby search

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the Google Places API in a JSP and getting the result in the form of JSON in javascript.The thing is that all the attributes of the JSON populate properly apart from the photos. I am using nearbySearch. From what I understand, the nearbySearch should give atleast one PlacePhoto object but it does not seem to work for me.

This is the nearbySearch

```
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

This is where I retrieve the URL and store it in photo var

```
photo = place.photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 35, 'maxHeight': 35 });
```

I am adding the image to a table cell through javascript.

```
var text3 = document.createElement('img');
text3.src = photo[0];
cell3.appendChild(text3);
```

This does not work. Any hints on how to make this work? I would appreciate examples as I am a newbie to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?"

Comment: The images are not displayed in that cell. Also, I am running a for loop to display restaurants getting the details from the JSON Array. It gets stuck on the first output (no matter what the output is) and does not display the rest of the restaurants.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but your `photo` variable is a string, not an array, so you could just do `text3.src = photo;` not `text3.src = photo[0];`

Comment: I think I figured out my problem. The nearbysearch is not returning a photo array. I just checked the JSON response and there was no photo. I did a details search with the placeid of a restaurant and voila the photo array came up. I am going to implement this in my code and let you know how it works out.